# Does "i" in a for loop default to a value of 1 in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables, default-value

I just have a basic question about a `for loop` in Python 3. It's a stupid, simple question, but I figure everyone else here is far more knowledgeable to me, and most answers are pretty bright! I do not profess to be intelligent, so I'd like some clarification. Running this loop seems to add a value of only one. I have defined `x` to be `1`, so this makes sense, but I didn't give `i` a true value and it seems to just naturally be `1`.

```py
for i in range(0, 50):
    x = 1
    i = x + i
    print(i)
```

I'm not getting an error, I'm just curious as to what's going on behind the scenes. Would love some explanation from someone who understands this more than I do!

Comment: At this point you're just confusing yourself, it seems. *You* told what values `i` should take by writing `i in range(0, 50)`. And then, you added a `1` to each value that `i` was taking in the range object. (starting from 0, if you notice. ) Change the Range around, and see what happens.

Comment: Well since you defined `x` to be `1`, you will each time print `x + ` that value. Since the range starts with `0`, then `i+x` starts with `1`.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see what you mean. The range is giving `i` its value, yes? Starting with 0, add x, then 1, add x, so on, so on.

Comment: Indeed. which means any extra work you do on the variable `i` is *thrown away* in the next iteration, because `i` is reassigned a new value from the Ranges.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what's happening. Thank you. I was trying to do something like increase the value of `i` each time the loop starts over, like a Fibonacci sequence. You're right, I was confusing myself. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, it appears so. I'm going to say this is a duplicate, but I love everyone's answers. Is there a way to keep everyone's responses once this gets marked a duplicate? Sorry again, I'm still pretty new to this and a slow learner.

Comment: Don't worry the responses don't go away. Marking dupes is a very important aspect of the "housekeeping" of this site though, to avoid dilution of answers. Essentially, the goal of the site stays to become a resource that everyone can easily search through and find answers for. Marking dupes helps that process. :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the `x=i` and `i=x+i` inside your loop.

```
for i in range(0, 50):
    print(i)
```

would work just fine and would output `0,1,2,3...47,48,49`. `i` is being set according to the `range(0,50)`. If you want `i` to start at 1 simply change the range to `range(1,50)`. Your code also added 1 to each `i` value so in order to account for this in the range you would need to do `range(1,51)` which would print `1,2,3...48,49,50`.

### Further Reading

I would recommend reading these to better understand how for loops work and also more info about ranges:

[Range()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)

[For Loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

Comment: You changed the behavior. To make it print the same numbers, you'd need to use `range(1, 51)`.